# Get shortest (not fastest) distance of a route with several waypoints from Google Maps Api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api, google-distancematrix-api

I have a route with several waypoints A, B, C, D ...
I want to get the shortest distance of this route through all waypoints in the same order.

Means, I don't want to optimize the order of the waypoints. I just want to get the shortest route. Google Distance Api gives me the **fastest** route and not the **shortest**.

Googles Direction API gives me all routes and then I can filter the shortest route but for this I have to create two loops. One that loops through the waypoints (A - B, B - C, C - D) and the in each leg loop through the possible routes to find the shortest.

I wonder if there is a better and more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

First, i hope you are not requesting 3 different routes WITH alternatives cause you are going to exhaust google api limits very quickly this way. Now the correct way of asking a route that passes through each waypoint is this in angularjs:

```
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        directionsService = new maps.DirectionsService();
});

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {});
```

with request being:

```
{
  origin: 'A',
  destination: 'D',
  waypoints: [
{
  location: 'C',
  stopover: false
}],
provideRouteAlternatives: false,
travelMode: 'DRIVING'
}
```

as in googleapi manual [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes)

Now, if you do have a lot of requests available to make to the google api key, you can just use as you said, provideRouteAlternatives: true, and find the one with the shortest distance.

The other alternative is to change the travelmode to walking as to this does give the shortes route, but this works very bad for streets with only one direction and stuff like this.